# JQuery Ajax call submits more times depending of time

Tags: jquery, ajax

I read similar questions to this problem but I couldn't find out why it does it here. 
Basically a jquery ajax call sends some info to be submitted. The problem is that the form is submitted the first time once, then second time twice, third time 4 times. I can't understand where is the problem. Could you please help?

```
$('#form10').submit(function () {
    //Get the data from all the fields
    var UserID = $('input[name=UserID]');
    var problemID = $('input[name=problemID]');
    var solution_text = $('textarea[name=solution_text]');
    var MM_insert = $('input[name=MM_insert]');

    //organize the data properly
    var data = 'UserID=' + UserID.val() + '&problemID=' + problemID.val() + '&solution_text=' + solution_text.val() + '&MM_insert=' + MM_insert.val();

    //show the loading sign
    $('.loading').show().delay(1200).fadeOut();
    //start the ajax
    $.ajax({
        //this is the php file that processes the data
        url: "/js/ajax/add-comment.php",
        //POST method is used
        type: "POST",
        //pass the data         
        data: data,
        //Do not cache the page
        cache: false,
        //success
        success: function (html) {
            //if process.php returned 1/true (success)
            if (html == 1) {
                //hide the gif
                $('.loading').fadeOut('slow');
                //show the success message
                $('#comment-success').delay(1000).slideDown('slow').delay(2000).slideUp('slow');
                $('#comments').load('/js/ajax/comments2.php?problemID=' + problemID.val());
                //if process.php returned 0/false (failed)
            } else {
                $('#error-msg2').show('slow');
            }
        }
    });
    //cancel the submit button default behaviours
    return false;
});
```

php back code

```
 .............

 if ((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "comments")) {
  $insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO solution (UserID, solution_date, problemID, solution_text) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)",
                   GetSQLValueString($UserID, "int"),
                   GetSQLValueString(date('Y-m-d H:i:s', mktime()), "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($problemID, "int"),
                   GetSQLValueString($solution_text, "text"));

 mysql_select_db($database_tccconn, $tccconn);
  $Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $tccconn) or die(mysql_error());

  if($Result1) { echo '1';}
  else
  { echo '0';}
```

}

the form

```
form method="post" action="" name="form10" id="form10">
   <input type="hidden" name="problemID" value="<?php echo $this->escape($this->item['problemID']);?>">
   <input type="hidden" name="UserID" value="<?php $identity = Zend_Auth::getInstance()->getIdentity(); ?>">  

   <textarea name="solution_text" id="solution_text" class="create" rows="6"></textarea>
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Reply to post" class="submit">
  <input type="hidden" name="MM_insert" value="comments">
  <div class="loading"></div>

  </form>
```

code frm comments2

```
mysql_select_db($database_tccconn, $tccconn);
$query_rstcomments = sprintf("SELECT solution.solutionID, solution.UserID, solution.solution_date, solution.solution_text,     solution.problemID, user.org_name FROM solution NATURAL JOIN user  WHERE solution.problemID = %s     ORDER BY solution.solutionID ASC", $colname_rstcomments);
$rstcomments = mysql_query($query_rstcomments, $tccconn) or die(mysql_error());
 $row_rstcomments = mysql_fetch_assoc($rstcomments);
$totalRows_rstcomments = mysql_num_rows($rstcomments);

 if($rstcomments) {

  do { ?>


<div class="comments-in-top">
      <div style="width: 166px; float: left">
       <div class="comments-in-bottom">
       Posted by<br /><strong><?php echo ucwords(stripslashes($row_rstcomments['org_name'])); ?></strong><br />On <?php  echo date("j F Y",strtotime($row_rstcomments['solution_date'])); ?><br />at <?php echo date("H:i",strtotime($row_rstcomments['solution_date'])); ?>
       </div>
    <div class="comments-in-bottom-b"></div>
      </div>
     <div class="comments-in-top-in">
       <?php echo nl2br(ucfirst(stripslashes($row_rstcomments['solution_text']))); ?>
     </div>
 </div>
<?php } while ($row_rstcomments = mysql_fetch_assoc($rstcomments));


} ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use unbind('submit') function while submitting form. This should fix it
(no change except line number 1 in below code)

```
$('#form10').unbind('submit').submit(function () {
    //Get the data from all the fields
    var UserID = $('input[name=UserID]');
    var problemID = $('input[name=problemID]');
    var solution_text = $('textarea[name=solution_text]');
    var MM_insert = $('input[name=MM_insert]');

    //organize the data properly
    var data = 'UserID=' + UserID.val() + '&problemID=' + problemID.val() + '&solution_text=' + solution_text.val() + '&MM_insert=' + MM_insert.val();

    //show the loading sign
    $('.loading').show().delay(1200).fadeOut();
    //start the ajax
    $.ajax({
        //this is the php file that processes the data
        url: "/js/ajax/add-comment.php",
        //POST method is used
        type: "POST",
        //pass the data         
        data: data,
        //Do not cache the page
        cache: false,
        //success
        success: function (html) {
            //if process.php returned 1/true (success)
            if (html == 1) {
                //hide the gif
                $('.loading').fadeOut('slow');
                //show the success message
                $('#comment-success').delay(1000).slideDown('slow').delay(2000).slideUp('slow');
                $('#comments').load('/js/ajax/comments2.php?problemID=' + problemID.val());
                //if process.php returned 0/false (failed)
            } else {
                $('#error-msg2').show('slow');
            }
        }
    });
    //cancel the submit button default behaviours
    return false;
});
```